# How to use GetPhysicalMonitorsFromIDirect3DDevice9 function in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to Control Monitor Brightness using `SetMonitorBrightness` function in C#.

According to its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-setmonitorbrightness), the monitor handle can be obtained by calling either `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR` or `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromIDirect3DDevice9` function.

I have already written a functioning C# code using `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR` by mimicking this [VB.net example](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/396275-controlling-screen-brightness-using-ddcci/).

Now, I tested it in different computers and found out that it does not function on some computers. I am 100% sure that the monitors support DDC/CI or whatever protocol.

Going back, my question is : how can i use the alternative [`GetPhysicalMonitorsFromIDirect3DDevice9` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/nf-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-getphysicalmonitorsfromidirect3ddevice9) instead?

I only have one monitor. I'm particularly clueless to how to get a pointer to the IDirect3DDevice9 interface of the Direct3D device that can be used to get a monitor handle.

I would appreciate if you could provide sample code in C#.

Comment: It seems you *can* call API functions, so what *exactly* do you need help with?

Comment: I barely understood what how this `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromIDirect3DDevice9` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/nf-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-getphysicalmonitorsfromidirect3ddevice9) work. So this would return a monitor handle which is what I need. But I don't know how to get a pointer to the IDirect3DDevice9 interface of the Direct3D device that was required of this function.